# File Statement - What does it do? / How does it work?

Tags: file, arduino

This will be weird - my code works fine, however I don't truly understand what the File statement does.  Is it creating a unique connect to the OS linker?  Is it declaring the name as a type?  And I think my lack of knowledge is keeping me from making (more) beautiful code.  I am using an Wemos D1, with SD/RTC shield and reading and writing from/to the SD card.  All that is fine.  But I am using 2 different routines for accessing the files rather than one generic routine with arguments.

```
File dataFile;                           //SD card file handle
File SDconFile;                          //Keep connect info SD file
```

And

```
char openFile(char RW, String FN) {      //Routine open SD file.  Only 1 open at a time.
  dataFile.close();                      //Ensure file status, before re-opening
  dataFile = SD.open(FN, RW);}           //Open Read at end.  Open at EOF for write/append

char openFile2(char RW, String FN) {      //Routine open SD file.  Only 1 open at a time.
  SDconFile.close();                      //Ensure file status, before re-opening
  SDconFile = SD.open(FN, RW);}           //Open Read at end.  Open at EOF for write/append
```

What I want is something like this:

```
char openFile(char RW, String FN, String <of xxx>) {     //Yes this is wrong
  xxx.close();                      //Ensure file status, before re-opening
  xxx = SD.open(FN, RW);}           //Open Read at end.  Open at EOF for write/append
```

Can you educate me please?

Answer (score 0):

`File dataFile;` declares a variable named `datafile` of the type `File`. If `File` is a class, the default constructor is called.

Just use a `File` reference as your third argument.

```
char openFile(char* fileName, byte rwMode, File& file) {
  ...
}
```

There's no need to open the file unless you read or write to it, so having a openFile function like that doesn't make too much sense to me though.